# Turning off identity temporary - Entity Framework 4.1 Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having a issue with ID being created again when I import data into the database that has a different ID. All the data imports correctly, its just that the identity (ID column) needs to be what the import is.

We have two keys in this model; ID and Identity. Identity is basically a unique instance name from the other datasource, so this will create an unique combination.

This is all set via the OnModelCreating on the DatabaseContext which is from class DbContext:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Observation>().HasKey(m => new {m.Instance, m.Id});
        modelBuilder.Entity<Observation>().Property(m => m.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(
            DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

The class looks like this:

```
public class Observation
{
    public string Instance { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The database context is only created once in this ASP.Net MVC 3 Application with Ninject.

I tried using a SQL  command to set identity off while adding a new entry, but with no success:

```
    public void SetIdentiyObservation(bool isOn)
    {
        var state = isOn ? "ON" : "OFF";
        _context.Database.SqlQuery<Observation>("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Observation @state", new SqlParameter("state", state));
    }
```

The created table structure looks like this in MSSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Observations](
[Instance] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Instance] ASC,
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any help on this is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input adrift, I solved this by going back to basic and removing the customer needs from the database needs. Ended up with a column to store the customer requirements for instance + id and then the database can live its own life with internal ID :)

Answer (score 0):

`SqlQuery<T>` returns an `IEnumerable`, and the sql query is not executed until you enumerate it.  If you add a `.ToList()` at the end of the statement, you'll get an exception saying that the syntax is incorrect.  You'll also run into problems when EF tries to map the result into an `Observation`.

I was finally able to get this to run using the following:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<object>("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Observation " + (isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")).ToList();
```

Which led to a final problem that I couldn't resolve.  Because `Id` is marked as generated by the database, EF does not include its value in the `INSERT` statement.

If you can find a way to alter the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` value on `Id` at runtime, you could add the entity using your context.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this, and the only way I could insert a row with a specified `Id` was to use the underlying connection and execute the sql needed.